How to test robots.txt that has disallows urls that contain somekeyword in ASP.NET MVC web app
I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. I added robots.txt to disallow a url that contains a key "somewords".
Please advise how can I test that a crawler is not allowed to access the page in local and test environment?
I cannot use any third-party tool in my environment since I need to get permission to use that.

use any website validation tool: "test robots.txt"

@Yehor Androsov which tool you refer. I cannot use any third party tool.

I guess you need to provide a reasoning to your manager why this is needed. Implementing a validation tool yourself would take weeks to make it comparable to tools already available online (reading specification files, implementation, tests etc).
